# Need to copy both the format and values in another sheet to the next row that is blank

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to copy this range A1 : BU17 to another sheet in the same spreadsheet in the next rows avaible.
I tried to use this:

```
function Copy() {

 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('x'); //replace with source ID
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Analysing'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
 var range = ss.getRange('A1:BU17'); //assign the range you want to copy
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('x'); //replace with destination ID
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Archive'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

}
```

I found this searching inside stackoverflow. It does copy my rows to the next one avaible but not the format too so is a total mess when i'm using it.
Ofc "X" is the id i know.
Thank you in advance if someone can help me.

Comment: Here is doc https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyFormatToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification? Please think of this as one of several answers.

You can use `copyTo()`. But there are some limitations.

- [`copyTo()` of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)) can copy both the formats and values to a sheet and a range in the same spreadsheet.
- [`copyTo()` of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)) cannot copy the data to a range and a sheet in other spreadsheet.
- [`copyTo()` of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)) can copy a sheet to other spreadsheet.
- [`copyTo()` of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)) cannot copy a range.

By reflecting them, your script can be modified as follows.

### Flow :

1. Retrieve a range which is a source.
2. Retrieve a range which is a destination.
3. Copy source sheet to destination sheet using `copyTo()` of Class Sheet.
4. Copy the source range to the destination range using `copyTo()` of Class Range.
5. Delete the sheet copied using `copyTo()` of Class Sheet.

### Sample script :

```
function Copy() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('x'); //replace with source ID
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Analysing'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
  var srcrange = ss.getRange('A1:BU17'); //assign the range you want to copy

  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('x'); //replace with destination ID
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Archive'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
  var dstrange = ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, srcrange.getHeight(), srcrange.getWidth());

  var dstSS = dstrange.getSheet().getParent();
  var copiedsheet = srcrange.getSheet().copyTo(dstSS);
  copiedsheet.getRange(srcrange.getA1Notation()).copyTo(dstrange);
  dstSS.deleteSheet(copiedsheet);
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: I can say only this : PERFECT! Thank you very very much!

Comment: @Asy Welcome. Thank you, too.

Comment: P.S. Thank you for teaching too, i understood much better some things now.